# Very slow CIFS/SMB performace

Tags: cifs, smb, nas

I switched from NFS to SMB/CIFS since the permission system of NFS annoyed me.
I never had performance issues while using NFS (1GB Lan) and had about 70-90 MB/s write and read speed while writing to my synology NAS.

**I test my write performance with dd (write 500MB to my SMB mount):**

```
[user@archStd01 Transfer]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user/NAS/Transfer/test bs=512 count=1000000
1000000+0 Datensätze ein
1000000+0 Datensätze aus
512000000 Bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) kopiert, 675.388 s, 758 kB/s
```

as you can see it performed very poor with an average of 758 kB/s

**My fstab:**

```
//192.168.1.100/Transfer /home/user/NAS/Transfer cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=3.0,rw 0 0
```

At the moment I go trough a few SMB manuals but I didnt find much about performance problems. Does anyone know where to start?

**//edit**
performance test with dd with 10MB blocksize

```
[user@archStd01 Transfer]$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user/NAS/Transfer/test bs=10M count=500
500+0 Datensätze ein
500+0 Datensätze aus
5242880000 Bytes (5.2 GB, 4.9 GiB) kopiert, 406.979 s, 12.9 MB/s
```

Its a lot better, but still far away from fast.

Comment: Try to test with a bigger block size and check if the performance stays the same.

Comment: Try at least with (significantly) larger `bs` if you insist on using `dd` as your "benchmark".

Comment: ok, I test with a bs of 10MB and update my original post with the results. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: when you type mount, what does it say about the *negotiated* version protocol?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro `//192.168.1.100/Transfer on /home/user/NAS/Transfer type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=admin,domain=ARBEITSGRUPPE,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=192.168.1.100,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`
it says: vers=3.0 ... should be good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just puzzling over a similar sounding CIFS performance problem. Transfers to and from a Windows client and our Samba server had good speed, but downloads from the server to two Ubuntu machines (running bionic) were slow. Using SCP to transfer instead of CIFS had no speed problems, so the problem wasn't the underlying network. Following the suggestions [on this ubuntuforums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2379232), I tried adding **cache=loose** to my Ubuntu client's cifs mount configuration in /etc/fstab, and speeds in both directions are now about what I expect (about x7-10 improvement in my case).

```
//server/share /media/localMountPoint cifs cache=loose,rw,...
```

However, as the poster cautions over on the ubuntuforums thread, according to the [mount.cifs man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-mount.cifs/):

> cache=loose can cause data corruption when multiple readers and writers are working on the same files.

I happen to be on a home network with very few users, so this is acceptable for me.

Comment: A task that once took 11/2 minutes took 3.5 seconds after this fix. This makes a huge difference!